# Multiply int column by float constant pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, constants, dataframe

I have a bunch of tipping bucket rainfall data recorded as number of tips per each minute interval. I have uploaded this to a pandas dataframe and I need to be able to multiply each individual column by a mm/tip calibration factor, but the column is type int and the factor is type float. I've tried:

df['Series'] = df['Series'].mul(constant) -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

df['Series'] *= constant  -> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

df['Series'] = df['Series'].astype(float) * constant  ->
  ValueError: could not convert string to float:

There's got to be an easy way to do this... Help?

**EDIT:**

Here's what my data looks like:

[image]

Here's how I read it in:

```
    def loaddata(filepaths):
        t1 = time.clock()
        for i,filepath in enumerate(filepaths):
            xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)
            df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], header=0, index_col=2, skiprows=[0,2,3,4], parse_dates=True)
            df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') 
            df = df.drop(['Decimal Year Day', 'Decimal Year Day.1', 'RECORD'], axis=1)
            df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(((df.index.asi8/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64)).values

    return df

files = ["London Water Balance.xlsx"]
Water = loaddata(files)
```

Heres the dtype

```
Water.dtypes

[L] Drainage NE             float64
[L] Drainage SE              object
[L] Embedded raingauge E     object
[L] External raingauge       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: pls show your data and how you read it in. also post ``df.dtypes``, you problably have ``object`` dtype data (with embeded ``None``). you can convert when you read it in (best way), or ``df.convert_objects())``. Things need to be the correct dtype to get efficiency.

Comment: I just edited the question. I think your right about the dtype. What would be the best way to convert in this case?

Comment: try df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) will force it to a numeric column and set non numeric to nan

Comment: I applied this command and the output confirmed that all columns were now float 64. I multiplied my constant immediately after using the *= operator and still get a type error, "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Comment: Actually this worked like a charm! Thank you! I forgot to assign the output from the conversion to the dataframe.

Comment: gr8 I put that up as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Will force it to a numeric column and set non-numeric elements to `nan`.